# Foretell something to someone or for someone?

Tags: prepositions

Foretell is a transitive verb, so it needs an object.

I believe it should be "foretell smth for someone," like "He can foretell my future for me."
Or does it work like to *tell*, meaning, no preposition is needed?

Comment: Garcia Marquez: Chronicle of a Death Foretold. The death was foretold. The writer foretold the death of Santiago Nasar.

Comment: Note that ***foretell*** is usually ***monotransitive***, unlike plain ***tell***, which is ***ditransitive***. So you probably *would* include the preposition (***to*** or ***for***, for example). But having said that, it's easy to find plenty of ditransitive usages in Google Books by searching for the sequence *[Someone] [**foretold him his**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22foretold+him+his%22) [destiny, future,...]*. Generally, though, I'd avoid using ***to foretell*** in the first place - it's very much a declining usage, that can often sound at least "dated" today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you! I've been discussing this verb with a teacher, and he insists on "to," but the general rule says to use "for" for nouns but "to" for verbs. That's why I'm in doubts.

Comment: If you are going to start using "foretell", I think it sounds best with only one object - i.e. the thing foretold.  Somehow it loses some power if you say "I foretold the end of the world... uh, to some people."

Comment: You're not alone in having doubts. Obviously ***to foretell*** is trivially derived from ***to tell*** in the first place, so *logically*, both versions of "the same" verb should have the same "valency" ("transitiveness", mono, single, or double). But [***to foretell***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+foretell&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20foretell%3B%2Cc0) has declined so much over the centuries that people can't easily conflate it with ***to tell*** any more. And "ditransitive" verbs are rare, so that aspect easily gets "lost".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be used either way.

"Three mages foretold the fate of the newborn prince for the king."

The mages acted at the behest of the king. There is no necessity that they did so in the king's presence.

"Three mages foretold the fate of the newborn prince to the king."

The mages spoke directly to the king in delivering their prophesy. They might have done so because they thought the king needed to know, but were not asked to do so by the king.